Associate a public IP address to a virtual machine
I have a task to organize the terraform state file.
There has been some manual deployments in the past and now I have to modify the terraform code in order to match what actaully is in the portal.
So far did quite alot of adjustemnts and I only have left to modify the VM deployemnt code in order to produce a Plan without any changes, add or destory.
So my VM deployement code look like this (/vm - folder):
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "publicip" {
    name                         = "ir-vm-publicip"
    location                     = var.location
    resource_group_name          = var.resource_group_name
    allocation_method            = "Static"
    tags = var.common_tags
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
    name                        = "ir-vm-nic"
    location                    = var.location
    resource_group_name         = var.resource_group_name

    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "nicconfig" 
        subnet_id                     =  azurerm_subnet.vm_endpoint.id 
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
        public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.publicip.id
    }
    tags = var.common_tags
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                          = "vm-adf-${var.env}"
  resource_group_name           = var.resource_group_name
  location                      = var.location
  network_interface_ids         = [azurerm_network_interface.nic.id]
  size                          = "Standard_DS1_v2"
  admin_username                = "adminuser"
  admin_password                = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.vm_login_password.value
  encryption_at_host_enabled   = false

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2016-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }


  tags = var.common_tags
}

Plan shows that it will remove my private and public address due to admin_password.
  # module.vm.azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "vm" {
      ~ admin_password               = (sensitive value) # forces replacement
      ~ computer_name                = "vm-adf-dev" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                           = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm-adf-dev" -> (known after apply)
        name                         = "vm-adf-dev"
      ~ private_ip_address           = "xx.x.x.x" -> (known after apply)
      ~ private_ip_addresses         = [
          - "xx.x.x.x",
        ] -> (known after apply)
      ~ public_ip_address            = "xx.xxx.xxx.xx" -> (known after apply)
      ~ public_ip_addresses          = [
          **- "xx.xxx.xx.xx"**,
        ] -> (known after apply)
      ~ size                         = "Standard_DS2_v2" -> "Standard_DS1_v2"
        tags                         = {
            "Application Name" = "dev nll-001"
            "Environment"      = "DEV"
        }
      ~ virtual_machine_id           = "xxxxxxxxx" -> (known after apply)
      + zone                         = (known after apply)
        # (21 unchanged attributes hidden)

      **- boot_diagnostics {
            # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)
        }**

      **- identity {
          - identity_ids = [] -> null
          - principal_id = "xxxxxx" -> null
          - tenant_id    = "xxxxxxxx" -> null
          - type         = "SystemAssigned" -> null
        }**

      ~ os_disk {
          ~ disk_size_gb              = 127 -> (known after apply)
          ~ name                      = "vm-adf-dev_OsDisk_1_" -> (known after apply)
            # (4 unchanged attributes hidden)
        }

        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }

How can I avoid this?
UPDATE
I have checked my terraform State and noticed that it is reading OLDER VERSION of the Secret. What could be the reason that its not picking up Current Version of the KV secret?
This is my main.tf file
locals {
  tenant_id       = "0c0c43247884"
  subscription_id = "d12a42377482"
  aad_group       = "a5e33bc6f389" }

locals {
  common_tags = {
    "Application Name" = "dev nll-001"
    "Environment"      = "DEV"
  }
  common_dns_tags = {
    "Environment" = "DEV"
  }
}

provider "azuread" {
  client_id     = var.azure_client_id
  client_secret = var.azure_client_secret
  tenant_id     = var.azure_tenant_id
}


# PROVIDER REGISTRATION
provider "azurerm" {
  storage_use_azuread        = false
  skip_provider_registration = true
  features {}
  tenant_id       = local.tenant_id
  subscription_id = local.subscription_id
  client_id       = var.azure_client_id
  client_secret   = var.azure_client_secret
}

# LOCALS
locals {
  location = "West Europe"
}

############# VM IR ################

module "vm" {
  source              = "./vm"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.dataplatform.name
  location            = local.location
  env                 = var.env
  common_tags         = local.common_tags

  # Networking
  vnet_name                         = module.vnet.vnet_name
  vnet_id                           = module.vnet.vnet_id
  vm_endpoint_subnet_address_prefix = module.subnet_ranges.network_cidr_blocks["vm-endpoint"]
  # adf_endpoint_subnet_id            = module.datafactory.adf_endpoint_subnet_id
  # sqlserver_endpoint_subnet_id      = module.sqlserver.sqlserver_endpoint_subnet_id

  # Secrets
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.admin.id

}

Also have versions.tf file:
# TERRAFORM CONFIG
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    container_name = "infrastructure"
    key            = "infrastructure.tfstate"
  }
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.52.0"
    }
    databricks = {
            source = "databrickslabs/databricks"
            version = "0.3.1"
        }
  }
}

The way I run my terraform plan is bellow
az login
export TENANT_ID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
export SUBSCRIPTION_ID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
export KEYVAULT_NAME="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
export TF_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
export TF_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET_NAME="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
export SP_CLIENT_SECRET_SECRET_NAME="sp-client-secret"
export SP_CLIENT_ID_SECRET_NAME="sp-client-id"
az login --tenant $TENANT_ID

export ARM_ACCESS_KEY=$(az keyvault secret show --name $TF_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET_NAME --vault-name $KEYVAULT_NAME --query value --output tsv);
export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$(az keyvault secret show --name $SP_CLIENT_ID_SECRET_NAME --vault-name $KEYVAULT_NAME --query value --output tsv);
export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$(az keyvault secret show --name $SP_CLIENT_SECRET_SECRET_NAME --vault-name $KEYVAULT_NAME --query value --output tsv);
export ARM_TENANT_ID=$TENANT_ID
export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$SUBSCRIPTION_ID

az login --service-principal -u $ARM_CLIENT_ID -p $ARM_CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $TENANT_ID
az account set -s $SUBSCRIPTION_ID

terraform init -reconfigure -backend-config="storage_account_name=${TF_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}" -backend-config="container_name=infrastructure" -backend-config="key=infrastructure.tfstate"


terraform plan -var "azure_client_secret=$ARM_CLIENT_SECRET" -var "azure_client_id=$ARM_CLIENT_ID"

Service princiapl has Get,List Secret permissions on the right Keyvault. I dont think its a good idea to manually update the state file with the right version of the KV secret.

Are those Update operations the only changes in your plan? I would suspect there is some other change to the resource causing those changes.

@MatthewSchuchard these too       - boot_diagnostics {
# (1 unchanged attribute hidden)
}
  - identity {
      - identity_ids = [] -> null
      - principal_id = "xxxxxxx" -> null
      - tenant_id    = "xxxxxxxx" -> null
      - type         = "SystemAssigned" -> null
    }


@MatthewSchuchard also there is one change for module.sqldatabase.azurerm_mssql_database.sqldatabase to add + license_type                = "LicenseIncluded" other than these nothing else

@MatthewSchuchard I have updated fully

The full plan information displays the reason for the re-creation:
~ admin_password               = (sensitive value) # forces replacement

The admin_password value cannot be known by the Terraform state during the import of the resource, and therefore the provider assumes it must be modified to match the config argument value, and therefore triggers a re-creation of the resource object. This can be circumvented with the lifecycle block ignore_changes parameter.
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  ...

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [admin_password]
  }
}

This will prevent the Azure provider from triggering a re-creation due to an incorrectly assumed necessary update to the admin_password. Note that if you do update the password and want the re-creation then the lifecycle block must be removed.

Is there no other solution to this?

I just checked the terraform state file and its shows the old version of the KV secret and not reading the Current Version. Not sure why. I have update my question with some more details
